# Different results of significance tests and confidence limits for the same data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

From a work survey, I got the following data, where ${n}$ is the positive response in the respective sample, ${N}$:

$${{N_1} = 167;  {n_1} = 34}$$
$${{N_2} = 235;  {n_2} = 68}$$

I used an online calculator to calculate the p-value and the confidence limits between these two samples at a 5% significance level (where ${{H_0}: {p_1}={p_2}; {H_A}: {p_1}\neq {p_2}}$). As a check, I repeated this on a second website.  Different answer.  I assumed there was an error in one of the online calculators, so I tried others. Yet even a wider a range of answers.  Some were similar (assuming an effect of rounding or using unbiased estimators) while others were quite different – to the extent of giving different results on significance!

On reviewing the online calculators, it would seem they use different methods (e.g. exact test, normal approximation, and various ‘corrections’) - some didn't even give a method.  I am interested to know why the results vary for the same data.  If different methods provide different results, how do we choose the ‘right’ one?

I have decided not to include the various results from the online calculators, as I don't want to influence the possible answers below. (However, feel free to include your results from the above data as part of your answer).

Comment: These are great questions but they lack sufficient focus for this site (and have been addressed in other threads).  Would you mind editing this post to focus on one definite question you would like to have answered?  (Afterwards, if that doesn't exhaust your curiosity, you may certainly go on to post follow-up questions in new threads.)

Comment: @whuber - edited to one question

Comment: Gosh this site is precious. Nice way to welcome a new contributor. Closed the question before I could edit it...

Comment: You can still edit it and it is still visible to all users.  Since you're new here, please take a few minutes before you proceed to review our [help].  It's worthwhile because we do some things differently.  BTW, the principal difficulty with your post -- even in its current form -- is it basically asks "how does statistics work?"  You will get many different and possibly even conflicting answers to that, which is one reason it's important to refine your question before people can begin answering it. Once they start answering, it's tough to make the question better.